# .htaccess with file extension removed and routing

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi,

I am in the middle of a project and I am using Mod_Rewrite and .htaccess to change some URLS. I want the file extension to be removed but once the user is signed in, they go to a folder called portal and then, /portal/index.php runs all the pages.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^portal/(.*)$ portal/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is not working, but I feel that I am close to the end result I'm hoping for.

The URL for pages should be like:

```
site.com/home
site.com/otherpage
```

and so on. These should be sent to:

```
/home.php
/otherpage.php
```

etc.

But once the user is logged in, the URL:

```
site.com/portal/index.php?page=section/section2/so-on
```

Should be re-written to:

```
site.com/portal/section/section2/so-on
```

With what I have, the first rule works, but the rest does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always keep the order of the rules from most specific to most generic in .htaccess. Your complete .htaccess should be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^portal/(.*)$ /portal/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

**Explanation:**

Rule 1 is simple. It is forwarding every `/portal/foo` URI which is not a physical file to `/portal/index.php?page=foo`. Flags L for last rule, QSA is for appending existing query string and NC is for ignore case matching.

Rule 2 is forwarding a URI like `/bar/` to `/bar.php` if it is not a real directory and there is actually a file calle `/bar.php`. Rexex `^(.*?)/?$` is there for stripping out trailing slash (note `/bar/` goes to `/bar.php`).

Comment: perfect thank you can you edit it to explain what `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` and `[L,QSA,NC]` and `^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]`  means and does just so i can understand it better. besides what i wanted it to do.

Comment: thank you. whats this part all about `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`

Comment: Pls check this link for more info on these options: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4124159.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder the rules as the first one sends /portal/section/section2/so-on to /portal/section/section2/so-on.

It needs to be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^portal/(.*)$ portal/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```